# How to map both json and form submit requests to the same controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

If I send data like this :

```
 $.ajax({
      url: $fooForm.action,
      data: $fooForm.serialize(),        
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
    });
```

This can be received by a controller that has the following signature :

```
 public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> checkEligibility(    Person person )
```

At another instance, I am sending the request like this :

```
$.ajax({
        url: $fooForm.action,
        data: $fooForm.serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
      });
```

This can be received by a controller with the following signature :

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> checkEligibility(@RequestBody Person person )
```

**I want to write a single method that can accept both the json POST as well as the simple POST, and give me the same Person object**

Comment: You have no JSON POST in your question, only form POSTS.

Answer (score 1):

If the x-www-form-urlencoded POST is part of a browser-based HTML forms application, DO NOT DO THIS

You should be using the POST-Redirect-GET pattern with HTML forms. Otherwise, when a user hits refresh in their browser they get that annoying popup.

And this is fundamentally at odds with patterns of a REST API

Comment: It's an AJAX request, so what's the point of POST-Redirect-GET?

Answer (score 0):

You can use polymorphism to make this feature work.

So, you need to create a BaseController.

```
@Controller
public class BaseController 


    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> checkEligibility(final Person person) {
        Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        body.put("person", person);
        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> entity = new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(body, HttpStatus.OK);
        // write some logic here ...
        return entity;
}
```

Next, you need to create RestController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/eligibility")
public class RestController extends BaseController {

    @Override
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "content-type=application/json" })
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> checkEligibility(final @RequestBody Person person) {
        return super.checkEligibility(person);
    }

}
```

After that, create Standart controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/eligibility")
public class StandartController extends BaseController {

    @Override
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> checkEligibility(final @ModelAttribute Person person) {
        return super.checkEligibility(person);
    }

}
```

Now this  should work.